# How to fetch the ID of the record using the name of the record?

Tags: salesforce, apex, sfdc, salesforce-flow

I have 2 objects (Account and case), where Case record will be created from an external source which passes account number as a input, Based on the account number I need to capture Account ID and assocciate the record.
Can you please suggest how to go forward for this requirement?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, you can use the following SOQL query.

```
String accountNumber = 'test23232';
List<Account> account_List = [SELECT Id,Name,AccountNumber FROM Account WHERE AccountNumber =:accountNumber];
```